# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.?

Tags: mod-rewrite

i have a simple rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ addnew/$0
```

however i get the

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

I am trying to rewrite

www.mysite.com/**anycharacter**

into

www.mysite.com/addnew/**anycharacter**

Answer (score 28):

Try the folllowing solution, it works for me.I hope this will work for you too.

1. BEFORE DOING ANYTHING - BACKUP YOUR DB!
2. Now, go into wordpress > settings > permalinks
3. Set it to one of the pretty permalink settings like //year/month/'
4. Open a text editor on your PC/Mac and open the .htaccess file you downloaded from your 
   webserver
5. Find this piece of code

   ```
   # BEGIN Wordpress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   # END WordPress
   ```
6. Replace it with this piece of code, courtesy of Scott Yang:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
   </IfModule>
   ```
7. Upload this code into the main domain root directory on your server and you're done.

Everything should work

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've just moved my WordPress installation from a subfolder to the root and this was causing me a lot of headaches. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This saved my day! For me, this particular line made it work  
  
`RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 14):

As RC already said, `.*` will also match `addnew/`. And since the *L* flag causes a reinjection of the rewritten rule, you will get an infinite recursion.

So adjust the rule so it doesn’t match your `addnew/`:

```
RewriteRule !^addnew/ addnew%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: in same situation (for me) it make infinite recursion

Comment: I solve my problem. My .htaccess have other redirects. It need to be disabled by RewriteCond.

Answer (score 3):

`.*`matches `addnew/`. Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]*$ addnew/$0
```