# .htaccess Wordpress network files not loading

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A problem have occurred when I'm trying to load files through my wordpress multisite network. With the original .htaccess file nothing but the entry page was visible. So the .htaccess file was rewritten according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611506/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-configuratio). This however caused a slight problem. Now the other sites that aren't the top level site can't load any external files (css, javascripts, images etc) that are added with the entire blog name (using directories so a trailing /dir/ is always added when visisting a subsite). So in this case a main.site.com/ works, whereas main.site.com/eng/ does work except that all files fetched through the theme etc doesn't load.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /basedir/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The errors that are received are:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

The apache error logs give me this:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

These errors are everything I get, so I am suspecting that there is something that make my redirect loop when I search for direct files instead of permalinks.

The site have been working on a different server that is identical apart from two things, the subdomain name and where in the /var/www/ directory the wordpress root was situated. I have changed everything that bare any resemblance to the old domain to the new domain (I have searched through the entire sql dump for the old information and it isn't any traces left).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a subdomain configured via apaches virtual hosts, then your "RewriteBase /basedir/" should be "RewriteBase /"