# Apache 2.4 - Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm running Apache 2.4 (64bit) and PHP 5.4.15 on windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and have noticed the following error in the Apache error log:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I have a multisite install of WordPress running and I think the error is coming from an error in the htaccess rewrites.

Looking at this post:
[Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611506/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-configuratio)

They suggest to replace this:

```
# BEGIN Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

with this piece of code, courtesy of Scott Yang:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

However, my WordPress htaccess looks a little different so I dont just want to replace my code just in case I inadvertently replace something that I need.

Here is my htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can anyone suggest what I need to change?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're getting into looping most likely due to these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
```

Just comment it out and try again in a new browser.

Comment: Comment out `RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]` also.

Comment: Thanks, anubhava. I'll let you know how it goes. The message sometimes takes a while to appear again in the logs.

Comment: I've also added LogLevel rewrite:trace3 to httpd.conf so hopefully that shows something.

Comment: Thanks, anubhava. It looks like commenting out `RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]` along with `RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]` solved the problem. Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: Does anyone know why these two rewrite rules exist at all? I created a question at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352817/why-does-multisite-bypass-wordpress-for-wp-content-wp-admin-wp-includes-and-p to address this and would love any input.

Answer (score 30):

This problem can be caused by requests for certain files that don't exist. For example, requests for files in wp-content/uploads/ where the file does not exist.

If this is the situation you're seeing, you can solve the problem by going to .htaccess and changing this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) - [L]
```

The underlying issue is that the rule above triggers a rewrite to the exact same url with a slash in front and because there was a rewrite, the newly rewritten request goes back through the rules again and the same rule is triggered. By changing that line's "$1" to "-", no rewrite happens and so the rewriting process does not start over again with the same URL.

It's possible that there's a difference in how apache 2.2 and 2.4 handle this situation of only-difference-is-a-slash-in-front and that's why the default rules provided by WordPress aren't working perfectly.

Comment: Thank you Justin. Very informative. So do you think it's best to keep the rewrite rule in (with a - instead of $1) rather than commenting it out?

Answer (score 5):

Solved this by adding following:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, an editor created a custom post type and a custom content type with the same slug. We fixed it by deleting one and resaving permalinks in [ WordPress › Tools › Settings ].

Hope this helps anyone.