# error 500 Cakephp 3 in subfolder with OVH

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've developed a web application based on Cakephp 3 on a dev server.
Now I'd like to go live. So I uploaded my cakephp folder to my new server with the following architecture :
www/site

Now when I try with the server's address like : http://test.cluster.ovh.net/site it's working fine.

But when I try to target (with ovh member area) my domains http://test.com and www.test.com on the subfolder www/site, my cakephp app is showing an Internal server error 500.

Here is my basic .htaccess in cakephp :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule    ^$    site/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) site/webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Error log :

> [Tue Mar 22 22:07:26 2016] [error] [client xx.xxx.xx.xx] [host
>   test.cluster.ovh.net] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal
>   redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

What should I do?

Thanks!

**EDIT : Solution found here :** [Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071324/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects)

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: 1st message edited

Comment: Have you read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756796/apache-2-4-request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable)? It is most likely caused by an bad redirect.

Comment: If you want the site to be accessible through `test.com` itself why are you putting it in a sub folder?

Comment: @Sevvlor I'm going to read it thanks

Comment: @ADmad Because there are other websites on this server

Comment: But doesn't each site have it's own document root?

Comment: www folder is common to all sites

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the destination you are rewriting to otherwise you will get a rewrite loop error because `site/webroot/` also matches the Rewrite pattern `(.*)` .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/webroot
 RewriteRule (.*) site/webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying

Comment: It's showing me a 404 error :
The requested URL /site/webroot/ was not found on this server.