# AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After the upgrade of my Ubuntu server, I tried open my wordpress website and I got this error in my error.log

**AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.**

message a get when i open the website.

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

I tried these 2 links bellow but my .htaccess is diferent so did not work.

[Apache 2.4 - Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756796/apache-2-4-request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable)

[Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611506/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-configuratio)

**.htaccess /root**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess /blog**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPres
```

**apache:**

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
```

someone know how to solve this?

thank you.

Comment: Maybe, you must move `.htaccess` to `/blog`.

Comment: hello, this .htaccess it is inside /blog

Comment: Did you move your wordpress install? I don't see how just upgrading your server would cause the error? What else did you change?

Comment: I upgraded everything today, new ubuntu  version, sql, mysql, apache, everything, I was just pressing ok ok ok ok :) hahaha

Comment: For people who end up here via Google, the solution to `AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable`  is probably here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022336/279564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was no php module for apache, and apache was interpreting  php as a text.

to solve this i did:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

apt-get install php7.0-mysql 

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: How did you find this was the problem?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE .htaccess from given following line of codes

````
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress```
````

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the limit however I guess its a loop. The following article should lead you into the correct direction:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Try with two different .htaccess. In the root folder:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

... or just make sure you redirect to the subfolder.

In subfolder:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Check your permalink settings home_url and blog_url. This may also cause an endless loop. Update your permalinks and search wp_options in order to insert the correct url / domain for your blog.

It also may be an Ubuntu specific configuration error try to raise limits or check for missing libraries like mod_rewrite.

Comment: Where do the redirects happen? From within wordpress or in the server? try to add echo 'hello'; die; in wp-config.php and check if it is reached?

Comment: nothing happen, the website was working correctly, after me update apache and Ubuntu this starts happen

Comment: So wp-config.php is never reached?

Comment: should i put this inside  right? : <?php

echo 'hello'; die;

Comment: Yeah just for one reload to check if it is reached.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133375/discussion-between-raduken-and-blackbam).

Comment: Sorry no time for chatting. You have to check if WordPress is ever reached or not. After you found out I can continue help by comment.

Answer (score 1):

Being on a shared hoster without access to configuration files, I could solve it in my case by re-saving the permalinks in the wp-admin backend.

Comment: This fixed it for me too

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this error message and I solved it.

I had this problem when upgrading from MacOS Catalina to Big Sur.

@vineetkumar and @blackbam put me on the right track.

Here is the modification I had to make in ***/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf*** :

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName vhost_for_https
   ServerAlias localhost
-  DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/anais_website"
+  DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/privateKey.key
-  <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/anais_website">
+  <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
     Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Require local
     Require ip 192.168.1.71
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```